# How to implement FurlEnum (mixin type) to held urls as objects?

Tags: python, enums

I'm trying to implement enum which keeps urls in [furl](https://github.com/gruns/furl) objects. Something like this:

```py
class FurlEnum(furl, Enum):
    SAMPLE_URL = furl('https://stackoverflow.com/')
```

Implementing it this way, however, leads to an error: `TypeError: metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases`. I managed to solve this by creating a metaclass that inherits from the base class of Enum and furl:

```py
class FurlEnumMeta(type(furl), type(Enum)):
    ...


class FurlEnum(furl, Enum, metaclass=FurlEnumMeta):
    value: furl
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.url

    SAMPLE_URL = furl('https://stackoverflow.com/')
```

This solved the problem of creating an enum class, but the solution has one significant problem that I do not know how to solve.
Let's take something like this as an example:

```py
sample_url = FurlEnum.SAMPLE_URL
print(sample_url.set(path='questions'))
print(FurlEnum.SAMPLE_URL.value)
print(FurlEnum.SAMPLE_URL)
```

The result is:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions
https://stackoverflow.com/
https://stackoverflow.com/questions
```

As you can see, the value of SAMPLE_URL was overwritten by the "set" operation with the original value preserved in the "value" field. Do you know how to prevent it, to get:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions
https://stackoverflow.com/
https://stackoverflow.com/
```

as a result of above prints?

I was trying different approaches, but none of them worked as I've expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first problem, why does `furl` need an ABC metaclass?  There is only one abstract method, which a base class `__init__` (or `__new__`) could check for -- also, if `furl` is not meant to itself be subclassed by other users, the abstract base class enforcements are less useful.

For the second problem: you've made the values of the `FurlEnum` *be* a `furl`, and also to have a `furl` as the value. (By default, the `.value` of a mixed enum member is the same type and value as the member itself, but not the same -- in other words, if you mutate one of them, the other is then out of sync.)

How I would solve this problem:

1. Remove the `ABC` dependency, which eliminates the need for a `FurlEnum` metaclass.
2. Make `furl`s be immutable -- like `tuple`, `str`, `int`, etc -- so that the various operations that change the `furl` value instead return a new `furl`, leaving the original one untouched.
3. Now `sample_url.set(path='questions')` will return a new, separate `furl` value, leaving `FurlEnum.SAMPLE_URL` unchanged.

---

Disclosure:  I am the author of the [Python stdlib `Enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html), the [`enum34` backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34), and the [Advanced Enumeration (`aenum`)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum)  library.

Comment: 1. I am not the author of furl, I am just using it, so I cannot change implementation on my own.
2. Is it possible somehow regarding to point above? I was trying to implement custom __setattr__ in enum, but it is not executed after creation of enum

Comment: @Grzegorz:  No.  The `furl` type is mutable, so inheriting from it makes the enum member mutable, so the value of the enum member and its `.value` attribute can diverge.  Note that making enum values mutable is not recommended.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of it and I am just wondering if it is possible to make it immutable?

Comment: @Grzegorz: It would be easier to fork and rewrite `furl`.

Comment: are there real possibility, that EnumType will be immutable as someone mention in https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/95004 ? I think that this will solve the problem I have

Comment: @Grzegorz: `EnumType` being immutable has no effect on enum members being mutable, which is where the problem is.